# Missing video ID from comment object

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve a comment on a video by comment ID using the youtube v3 data api.

Here's the documentation part I am concerned with: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#resource

In the resource documentation, there's a property called "videoId" that I don't get when using this API call:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet,id&key={YOUR_KEY_HERE}&id=z13cdfiygorrst1f422fuzi5eqevcdwsf

Edit: I have already been trying working around this problem to no avail, also started an issue on google issue tracker to no answer. As far as I know, the youtube-data-api tag is where the developers track the issues in the API.

Comment: Code used? please.

Comment: I am writing my own API implementation, not using any libraries. The problem is present when just using the URLs in the post itself. If you put your own key, you'll see that the videoId (that's present in the documentation) is not there on the comment response.

Comment: Please provide complete, minimal and verifiable code. Also, share with us the full stack trace if any.

Comment: How did you get the comment ID? Can you verify it is a comment on a video and not something else?

Comment: @johnh10 I got it by using the commentThreads endpoint to try to get an example to try this endpoint with.

Comment: @d.datul1990 What do you mean minimal verifiable code? Why does the code/stack trace is irrelevant here, it's purely a question regarding the endpoint results of the above URLs

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the comments endpoint does not return the videoId, but the commentThreads does.

So calling https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,id&key={YOUR_KEY_HERE}&id=z13cdfiygorrst1f422fuzi5eqevcdwsf and parsing the result to get the proper comment in the comment threads (that includes replies) seems like a reasonable workaround...

Comment: Yes, but in this case, I want to get some comments by their specific IDs, which is not supported in the commentThreads endpoint, rather the comments endpoint